# Maintaing changes on the previous page

Tags: asp.net

I have a page in asp.net by clicking on the grid in the page it takes me to the detail page,on this page i have a back button (not browser back) by clicking on the button it takes me again to the search page.
i want to see the page with changes which i have made before coming to the detail page,also i want to disable back button of browser.
i dont want to use session variable or viewstate variable.
is there any property for this scenario.

yours sincerely
Talha khan

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable the browser back button. End of story. Sorry.

What changes are you making to the grid, where is it getting it's data from? You could use a cookie to store the previous pages' state if you don't want to use session or viewstate.

Comment: thanks for replying,Grid is just showing me records,i m clicking on the link button in the grid and it takes me to the detail page.

Answer (score 0):

If the the amount of data you need to track is relatively small (in your case this would probably be a search query) you can use query string to pass the state to the detail page (which can be later passed back to the search page).

You can also use browser cookies to persist the state but I wouldn't do that (at least because they're not designed for this kind of interaction).

-- Pavel

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to solve this.

1. The first that comes to mind is to change the page to AJAX. AJAX would not force a page jump forward, hence there will be nowhere to go back to.
2. The second way is to have a check on the previouis page, for example set "Session("if_search_go_here") = Request.Url.PathAndQuery" and unset it at the right place. If this is set then the search page will just forward you to the detils page again.

   - probably more. :)